# How to set up a minimap in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to get an overview of my code and would like to use a minimap in VS Code. 
I did not find an option to set this up in the menus. I am using VS Code 1.9.

Comment: Very interesting is the ability to add "section headers" - marker text to the minimap with vscode Insiders v1.88. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195302/836330.  Basically special comment text that you add to your code that will be shown in the minimap.

Answer (score 35):

**Starting with version 1.10** (Feb 2017) vscode supports minimaps. 
You can switch this function on via the preferences. Just follow these steps:

1. open vscode
2. File
3. Preferences
4. Settings

On the right pane you see your own custom settings. There you can add the following settings:

```
   // Controls if the minimap is shown
  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,
```

If this is the first setting you need to surround this with curly brackets and remove the tailing comme. If you have already one or more please keep in mind this is JSON so you need to separate key:values with a comma.

Comment: In macOS, the global shortcut to open Preferences in an app still work here: `cmd + ,` It's an easy way to skip steps 1-3.

Answer (score 8):

Adding the following to `settings.json` will also highlight where you are on the map:

```
"editor.minimap.showSlider": "always"
```

Answer (score 6):

Additionally, to render blocks instead of characters for better visualization in the Minimap:

```
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters":false
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to settings.json will also hide the minimap and show it when you hover over it:

```
"editor.minimap.autohide": true
```

I also have the following settings:

For showing a simplified version instead of characters

```
"editor.minimap.renderCharacters": false
```

Limiting the total width of the minimap:

```
"editor.minimap.maxColumn": 100,
```

Other options with their default values can be found in the [Default Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_default-settings) of VS Code:

```
  // Controls whether the minimap is hidden automatically.
  "editor.minimap.autohide": false,

  // Controls whether the minimap is shown.
  "editor.minimap.enabled": true,

  // Limit the width of the minimap to render at most a certain number of columns.
  "editor.minimap.maxColumn": 120,

  // Render the actual characters on a line as opposed to color blocks.
  "editor.minimap.renderCharacters": true,

  // Scale of content drawn in the minimap: 1, 2 or 3.
  "editor.minimap.scale": 1,

  // Controls when the minimap slider is shown.
  "editor.minimap.showSlider": "mouseover",

  // Controls the side where to render the minimap.
  "editor.minimap.side": "right",

  // Controls the size of the minimap.
  //  - proportional: The minimap has the same size as the editor contents (and might scroll).
  //  - fill: The minimap will stretch or shrink as necessary to fill the height of the editor (no scrolling).
  //  - fit: The minimap will shrink as necessary to never be larger than the editor (no scrolling).
  "editor.minimap.size": "proportional",
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update to version 1.10+ and add `"editor.minimap.enabled": true` to your user or workspace settings, which can be opened with `Ctrl+,`.

Comment: Please specify a little better add that line where? Settings.json?

Answer (score 1):

Since the questions is "how to configure it" I will give what I've found is the most useful configuration of the minimap feature.

This is how it looks in my editor:

[image: Minimap example in VScode]

This is effectively about 1/3 height and only the first 40 columns. But still just readable. It makes it so I can quickly grab the minimap slider and scrub through a file.

Here is my minimap config:

[image: VScode Minimap Settings]

Answer (score 0):

In current VS Code versions, you can simply enable and disable minimap under view->Show minimap.This is reference from Visual studio code version 1.55.2. This way we don't need to edit json settings file.

[image]