# Vscode - How to add #region color to Minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I render the `#region` color in the Minimap inside vscode editor?

[image]

I've searched inside all vscode settings, but I cannot find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Closer to what you wanted is the ability to set `region` markers - basically a header text - into your minimap.  This is in Insiders v1.88 now and presumably will be in Stable v1.88 early April, 2024.

Here is a demo:

[image: markers - section headers in minimap]

You can make these markers in various ways:

```
// MARK: activate

// region snippetProvider   or whatever the region syntax is for your language

/* MARK: registerCommand
```

with or without the whitespace after the comment characters, so `//MARK: activate` or `//      MARK: activate` would work as well.  As would `// MARK:activate` or `// MARK:     activate`.

What is key are the `MARK:` (with no whitespace before the `:`) or `region`  terms.  `// endregion something` will not add anything to the minimap.

Here are the relevant settings:

```
Editor > Minimap: Section Header Font Size

Editor > Minimap: Show Mark Section Headers     // to use MARK:

Editor > Minimap: Show Region Section Headers   // to use region:
```

with `Editor > Minimap: Enabled` of course.