# A vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType that is showed on minimap

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to make more "navigable" my code on VSCode using some colors on the editor using the function vscode.window.createTextEditorDecorationType, but the colored decoration is not showed on the minimap. It is really important for taking the absolute advantage of this feature. How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: you can look at the Highlight extension on how it does the decoration and show on minimap

Comment: I admit that I don't know how to find the base highlight manager extension https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions

Comment: have you looked in the market place, there are the extensions

Comment: For the moment, the only thing that I could do is submitting a feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136360

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195302/836330 may be of interest to you - you can add "section headers text markers` into your minimaps with vscode v1.88.